# RPi 2b SSH usually disconnects!

Tags: ssh

I use my Raspberry pi to connect a server using SSHFS, mounting a folder on the server to a folder on my Pi. My pi acts as a client. My Pi's OS is Linus. I use cable to connect the network, not WiFi

My connecting code is :
ssh pi@IPaddress

However, after around 20 seconds, there is no response. It just shows 'Write failed; Broken pipe.'

I tried adding some 'TCPKeepAlive no','ServerAliveInterval 10' and 'ServerAliveCountMax 200' in my ~/.ssh/config, /etc/ssh/ssh_config, /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

After rebooting my Pi, it still disconnected after several seconds.

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that there's not a problem with your server?

Comment: Yeah. I'm pretty sure. I can use my mac to connect my server. At least in one day, it connects successfully without any disconnection.

Comment: what are the usernames on your server?  do you have a server user named pi?  if not, you should use `ssh username@ipaddress`

Comment: Yeah, my server has a name pi...

Comment: can you access the rest of the internet from the pi?

Comment: Usually, it disconnects...I thought it maybe my local network issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use a local network, mounting to the IP address with the same first three parts. Then it can connect for a long time. Therefore, I thought it should be my network issue. I'll try to use wifi to see if my network works or not!
Thanks!